# pyspark logical conjunction for sql

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, vertica

> I am running spark 1.6 on 3 VMs (i.e. 1x master; 2x slaves) all with 8
>   cores ,  retrieve data from my Vertica database to work on it the
>   below query is working well on  vertica db but but its doesn't work on
>   pyspark , Spark DataFrames support predicate push-down with JDBC
>   sources but term predicate is used in a strict SQL meaning. It means
>   it covers only WHERE clause. Moreover it looks like it is limited to
>   the logical conjunction (no IN and OR I am afraid) and simple
>   predicates, it there anyway to execute the below query as is ?

```
    url = "*******"
    properties = {
        "user": "*****",
        "password": "*******",
        "driver": "com.vertica.jdbc.Driver"
    }
df = (sqlContext.read.format("jdbc")
.options(url=url, dbtable='(SELECT min(date(time_stamp)) mindate,max(date(time_stamp)) maxdate,count (distinct date(time_stamp)) noofdays, subscriber, server_hostname, sum(bytes_in) DL, sum(bytes_out) UL, sum(connections_out) conn from traffic.stats where \$CONDITIONS and SUBSCRIBER like '41601%' and date(time_stamp) between '2019-01-25' and '2019-01-29'and signature_service_category = 'Web Browsing' and (signature_service_name = 'SSL v3' or signature_service_name = 'HTTP2 over TLS') and server_hostname not like '%.googleapis.%' and server_hostname not like '%.google.%' and server_hostname <> 'doubleclick.net'  and server_hostname <> 'youtube.com'  and server_hostname <> 'googleadservices.com'  and server_hostname <> 'app-measurement.com' and server_hostname <> 'gstatic.com' and server_hostname <> 'googlesyndication.com' and server_hostname <> 'google-analytics.com'  and server_hostname <> 'googleusercontent.com'  and server_hostname <> 'ggpht.com'  and server_hostname <> 'googletagmanager.com' and server_hostname is not null group by subscriber, server_hostname)temp',
         **properties)
                .load()).show()
```

Comment: Can you please post the error you receive when you try to execute this statement?

Comment: invalid syntax , even if I'm trying to do the below query  `select date(time_stamp) AS DATE, (subscriber) AS IMSI, (server_hostname) AS WEBSITE, (bytes_in) AS DOWNLINK, (bytes_out) AS UPLINK,(connections_out) AS CONNECTION from traffic.stats WHERE DATE between '2019-02-02' & '2019-01-01' `  (Caused by: com.vertica.support.exceptions.SyntaxErrorException: [Vertica][VJDBC](4856) ERROR: Syntax error at or near ")"
)